# apache2.service is not active, cannot reload

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy my server python application on VPS (Ubuntu 16.04.2, Apache2) and while I write `sudo service apache2 reload` I receive such error: `apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.`

When I want to see my systemctl I get this.

```
systemctl status apache2.service

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2017-03-11 19:34:43 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 10065 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9832 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10045 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 11 19:34:42 kristicbot systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Mar 11 19:34:42 kristicbot apache2[10045]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot apache2[10045]: Action 'start' failed.
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot apache2[10045]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot apache2[10045]:  *
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot apache2[10065]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot apache2[10065]:  *
Mar 11 19:34:43 kristicbot systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Mar 11 19:35:00 kristicbot systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

Before that I made some corrections in my 000-default.conf file. I changed it the following way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        WSGIDaemonProcess botserver
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/bot/botserver.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/html/bot/>
                WSGIProcessGroup botserver
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My botserver.py is pretty simple:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
        return "Hello {}".format(2+2)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')

~
```

My botserver.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'var/www/html/bot')
from botserver import app as application
```

What could cause this problem, and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Searching for that error shows this as first result http://askubuntu.com/questions/837372/apache2-service-is-not-active-cannot-reload , try to see if this applies to your exact case and if it solves the problem.

Comment: @GerryHernandez although I have seen that answer, I found my mistake after precise overlook. printing error.log helped me!